# Passing a leaflet layer's popup to textOutput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

In a shiny app, is it possible to pass a selected leaflet layer's popup value to a textOutput outside of the leafletOutput? I've come across [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095499/how-can-i-pass-info-from-leaflet-popup-to-shiny-output) which seems to be asking the same thing, however in the answer it seems they stop at printing the layerId to the console. Is there any way to access any other information besides "lat" "lng" and "id", such as the popup?

This is basically where I'm stuck:

```
popup <- paste0("County Name: ", counties$NAME, "<br>", 
                "Population: ", counties$POP, "<br>", 
                "Unemployment Percentage: ", counties$UNEMP
         )
ID <- as.vector(counties$CNTY_ID)

map2 <-leaflet() %>%
 addPolygons(data = counties, layerId = ID, popup = popup
 )

observe({
event <- input$map2_shape_click

# I'm assuming what I need to do goes here

if (is.null(event))
  return()
print(event)      
})

output$popupOut <- renderText(event)
```